# Why doesn't this query return the get_absolute_url? But another one does

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to learn why this query renders an empty `<a href="">Some project</a>` in my template. Am I missing the `pk`?

```
from django import template
from architecture.models import Architecture
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('cubo/winnings.html')
def winnings():
    winnings = Architecture.objects.values('year', 'project').order_by('year').filter(won=True)
    return {'winnings': winnings}
```

But this query do work.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('cubo/winnings.html')
def winnings():
    winnings = Architecture.objects.filter(won=True).order_by('-year')
    return {'winnings': winnings}
```

the template: **cubo/winnings.html**

```
<ul>
    {% for win in winnings|dictsortreversed:"year" %}
        <li>
            {{ win.year|date:"Y" }} - <a href="{{ win.get_absolute_url }}">{{ win.project }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And for reference here is the **models.py**

```
from autoslug.fields import AutoSlugField
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Architecture(models.Model):
    live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    won = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    year = models.DateField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    typology = models.ManyToManyField(Typology)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='project', max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('architecture-detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [`Queryset.values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) documentation, you can see that when `values` is used, the results come in the form of dictionaries instead of model instances:

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

Your template is probably failing when trying to call the `get_absolute_url` method on a dictionary.

---

It is probably possible to work around using [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). Something like this (**not tested**):

```
winnings = (Architecture.objects
            .annotate(url=reverse('architecture-detail',
                                  args=[str(F('slug')])
            .values('year', 'project', 'url')
            .order_by('year')
            .filter(won=True))
```

(see [query expressions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for more detail about the `F` class)

and editing the template like this:

```
{{ win.year|date:"Y" }} - <a href="{{ win.url }}">{{ win.project }}</a>
```

Comment: Does annotating and using reverse in this context actually work? Whenever I've tried it, it fails to resolve the F value into an actual value.

Comment: @Programming123 do you get an error? if yes please provide the error message. If not you should probably post a new question.

Comment: Yes, was trying to use reverse as part of an annotation, and I found that Django wasn't inserting the F() value, but was instead treating the F() value as a string literal. If the annotation can be made to work with reverse (or other functions) it would be great.